# Beautiful soup returns nothing

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the HTML code:

```
<div xmlns="" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;">42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server</div>
```

I am trying to print `42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server` using Beautiful Soup but the output is an empty element i.e, `[]`

This is my Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request as urllib2

with open(r"C:\Users\sourabhk076\Documents\CBS_1.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'background':'#fdc431'})

print(divs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background` is not an attribute of the `div` tag. The attributes of the `div` tag are:

```
{'xmlns': '', 'style': 'box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;'}
```

So, either you'll have to use

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;'}
```

or, you can use the `lambda` function to check if `background: #fdc431` is in the `style` attribute value, like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div xmlns="" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;">42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server</div>', 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(lambda t: t.name == 'div' and 'background: #fdc431' in t['style']).text)
# 42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server
```

or, you can use RegEx, as shown by [Jatimir in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669665/7832176).

Comment: You can do it cleaner :) `soup.find('div', style=lambda s: 'background: #fdc431' in s)`

Comment: @Jatimir, thanks for the suggestion. It is a better solution here. But, I used the other one as it shows the scope of what you can do using `lambda`.

Comment: sure, mentioning function as one of the possible [filters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) is a great idea. I discovered it thanks to you :D

Answer (score 2):

Solution with [regexes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open(r"C:\Users\sourabhk076\Documents\CBS_1.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), 'html.parser')
```

Let's find the div that matches the following regular expression: `background:\s*#fdc431;`. `\s` matches a single Unicode whitespace character. I assumed that there can be 0 or more whitespaces so I added the `*` modifier to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE. You can read more about regexes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) as they sometimes come in handy. I also recommend you this [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/).

```
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': re.compile(r'background:\s*#fdc431;')})
```

This however is equivalent to:

```
div = soup.find('div', style=re.compile(r'background:\s*#fdc431;'))
```

You can read about that in the official documentation of [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

Worth reading are also the sections about the [kinds of filters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) you can provide to the `find` and other similar methods.

You can supply either a string, regular expression, list, `True` or a function, as shown by [Keyur Potdar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669516/beautiful-soup-returns-nothing/49669683#49669683) in his anwser.

Assuming the div exists we can get its text by:

```
>>> div.text
'42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server'
```